# Equivalent definitions of independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

All random variables are defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. I'm trying to prove a proposition at page 17 from [this](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf) lecture note. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Definition 3.3.** Two $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables $X_1, X_2$ are independent if
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \leq t_1, X_2 \leq t_2\right\}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \leq t_1\right\}\right) \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_2 \leq t_2\right\}\right), \quad \forall t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

**Notation.** $X_1 \perp X_2$.

**Proposition 3.4.** $X_1, X_2$ are independent if and only if
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \in B_1, X_2 \in B_2\right\}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \in B_1\right\}\right) \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_2 \in B_2\right\}\right), \quad \forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$

---

**Proof:** One direction is clear. Let's prove the other one. Let $\mathbb J := \{(-\infty, t] : t \in \mathbb R\}$. Then $\mathbb J$ is a $\pi$-system. Assume that $X_1 \perp X_2$.

- Fix $A \in \mathbb J$. We will prove that
  $$
  \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A, X_2 \in B\}) = \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\}) \mathbb P (\{X_2 \in B\}) \quad (\star)
  $$
  for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\mathcal C := \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) : (\star) \text{ hold}\}$. Clearly, $\Omega \in \mathcal C$. If $B \in \mathcal C$ then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A, X_2 \in B^c\}) &= \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\}) - \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A, X_2 \in B\}) \\
&= \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\}) - \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\}) \mathbb P (\{X_2 \in B\}) \\
&= \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\} \mathbb P (\{X_2 \in B^c\}),
\end{align}
$$
and thus $B^c \in \mathcal C$. If $(B_n) \subset \mathcal C$ is pairwise disjoint, then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A, X_2 \in \bigcup B_n\}) &=  \sum_n\mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A, X_2 \in B_n\}) \\
&= \sum_n \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\}) \mathbb P (\{X_2 \in B_n\}) \\
&= \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\}) \sum_n  \mathbb P (\{X_2 \in B_n\}) \\
&= \mathbb P (\{X_1 \in A\})  \mathbb P (\{X_2 \in \bigcup B_n\}),
\end{align}
$$
and thus $\bigcup B_n \in \mathcal C$. It follows that $\mathcal C$ is a $\lambda$-system. Clearly, $\mathbb J \subset \mathcal C$. Then by Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, we get $\sigma(\mathbb J) \subset \mathcal C$ and thus $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathcal C$.

- Fix $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. We will prove that $(\star)$ holds for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\mathcal D := \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) : (\star) \text{ hold}\}$. Clearly, $\Omega \in \mathcal D$. We have proved above that $\mathbb J \subset \mathcal D$. Just as previously, we can show that $\mathcal D$ is a $\lambda$-system. Then by Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, we get $\sigma(\mathbb J) \subset \mathcal D$ and thus $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathcal D$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. To check independence, it suffices to check independence on any generating $\pi$-system.

I would recommend replacing "Clearly, $\mathbb J\subseteq \mathcal C$" with saying this containment follows from Def 3.3. You haven't explicitly mentioned anywhere else, where you make use of the assumption.